# sign_in form and sign_up form on homepage using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

This is a basic and common problem, and I'd like to clear it once and for all. (tried for days)

I have two forms, which are on the homepage (whos controller is `static_pages_controller`).
One form is for signing in, the other for signin up.

The `sign_in` form uses the `sessions_controller` using the `create` action.

The `sign_up` form uses the `users_controller` using the `create` action.

When using `form_tag` how can you specify which controller it should go to and what action it should take?

The following code is for the signup page:
`

```
<%= form_tag(users_path) do%>

<%= label_tag :name %>
<%= text_field_tag :name %>

<%= label_tag :email %>
<%= text_field_tag :email %>

<%= label_tag :password %>
<%= password_field_tag :password %>

<%= label_tag :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
<%= password_field_tag :password_confirmation %>

<%= submit_tag "Create my account" , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>`
```

I know there are options like `form_tag({:controller => "user", :action => "create"}, :method => "post", :class => "nifty_form")` but none seems to work. Same for sign_in.  Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "none seems to work"? Do you mean that it is way too complicated for your use? Or are you getting an error? Because it says in the official guides that the hash version of params in `form_tag` generates a form tag.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify. None create a new user.The best I got is that it routes to the signup page, or to get a routing error saying `No route matches [POST] "/assets"`

Comment: I also tried this:

`<%= form_tag users_path, :method => "post" do %>`

The form lies in the home page. when I submit the form it redirects me to the signup page with all the error messages such as "Name field blank" although I filled the original form correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When the page renders, the HTML form will have an action.  You could use javascript to change the action for the form depending on whether they are signing up or signing in.

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding. There are two forms, so there is no need for javascript. The issue is that there are two seperate controllers to be considered. For loging in, Form1 should use the sessions controller. For signing up, Form2 should use the users controller.
The question is how to specifically state which controller and model the form should target. Note that the form is in the home page, whose default controller is the static_pages_controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a tiny misunderstanding here (or I misinterpreted your question). You cannot specify the target controller and action in `form_field`, at least not directly. Your only responsibility there is to:

- Set the correct **URL** for the form (which can be *generated* by providing a controller and an action, but that's a different story)
- Set the correct HTTP **method** for the form (Rails does this automatically, and if it doesn't, it will default to POST)

Then the mapping between the path and the controller/action is done in `routes.rb`. For example:

```
resource :session, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :users
```

This generates the following path => controller/action mappings:

```
GET    /session/new  =>  sessions#new        (new_session_path)
POST   /session      =>  sessions#create     (session_path)
DELETE /session      =>  sessions#destroy

GET    /users/new  =>  users#new             (new_user_path)
POST   /users      =>  users#create          (users_path)
... etc ...
```

So, if you need to make the form submit to sessions#create, the URL must be `session_path` and the method must be `POST`. The same applies for `users_path`.
The following code does that for the sign in form:

```
<%= form_tag session_path do %>
  <!-- fields -->
<% end %>
```

The sign up form is a bit different because this form is for a model object, so you can use `form_for` (assuming you have `@new_user = User.new` in your controller):

```
<%= form_for @new_user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <!-- etc -->
<% end %>
```

Since your form looks OK, the cause of your problem will probably be in `routes.rb`. Run `rake routes` to check which controller/action your routes point to.

Comment: I am signing up two different models. Patients and Doctors. I have a dropdown in the form where people can choose, but have not yet figured out how I could pass this as an indicator for the routes to choose which controller it should go to. (But that's another question).
Here I am trying to resolve the problem without the choice, and just want to sign people in using form_tag.
Currently I am trying it using this code.

`<%= form_tag({:controller => "users", :action => "/users"}, :method => "post", :class => "nifty_form") do %>`

it gives me a routes error. what is action and what method?

Comment: Here you are trying to generate the form submission URL by giving it a controller and an action name. But the _action_ parameter here should be the target Rails action and **not** the value that gets into the _action_ HTML parameter (they have the same name so no wonder it seems confusing...). So if you create the user in the _UsersController#create_ method, your code should be the following: `{:controller => "users", :action => "create"}`, or just `users_path`. If your routes are set up correctly, they both should generate HTML code similar to this: `<form method="post" action="/users"> ...`

Comment: If you're still stuck, add your `routes.rb` and the complete code of your form to your question because I'm stabbing in the dark here...